# How many times can I beat my animals without killing them?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I often go mining with my trusty cat in tow. However he is a bit clumsy and sometimes wanders infront of my pickaxe mid-swing, so I accidentally hit him. If I do this then I am more careful with my pickaxe for a while, although sometimes it happens again and he catches one in the face once more.

How often can I do this before he dies? Is it just (as I suspect) a time delay - I can hit him once at a time as often as I like, but if the strikes land within a short period of time (a few seconds perhaps) then I risk killing him, but if I spread out the hits over longer periods and keep them as single strikes then he'll recover and be fine?

Or, does each hit weaken him overall and so at some point one of my individual accidental hits will result in him keeling over and dying? Is it the same pattern for all animals?

Comment: [Pets.SE] is in beta...

Comment: That title. PETA would be impressed. Especially after what they did to [Pokémon](http://features.peta.org/pokemon-black-and-white-parody/)

Comment: You should mention the platform in question in the question body. I almost missed your comment on the answer.

Comment: @3ventic: Fair enough. Although I didn't believe this was a question specific to the console platform as the details of the question apply to all versions of the game (except maybe MCPE).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend installing the damage indicators mod because it displays mobs health at the top left, but never the less the health of the cat starts at 5 hearts of health so 1/2 a players. Depending on the tier of the pick it deals different amount of damage same goes with swords. The cat does not regenerate and is hardish to heal. Here is a quote from the gampedia website on how to heal the cat. "Cats cannot be healed by being fed fish, unlike tamed Wolves with meat. The only way to heal a cat is to use a splash potion of Healing or Regeneration on it." I wish you best of luck with your cat :D!

Comment: I'm on XBox so can't install any mods. I assume the damage patterns are the same as on the 'desktop' version of the game though. One thing I have just learned in the 15 minutes since asking this question - don't try digging upwards under a lake with your cat with you. He'll likely drown :( No matter, I have another one standing guard at my house, so I'll experiment in him instead.